# Zero-rate USD Curve

Tags: discount-factor-curve

Good day, I have inputs:
Libor 1D, 1M, 2m, 3m. 
FRA 3x6, 3x9, 3x12
IRS 2Y, 30Y.

What formula should I use to construct zero rate curve?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to bootstrap a zero curve from your market data. This process is iterative in the sense that the implied zero rates for your short-term LIBOR rates are calculated before using those rates to bootstrap your zero rates implied by your FRAs. You will need to bootstrap for each time-point defined by your instruments.

A good reference for you would be (no multi-curve) [Methods for Constructing a Yield Curve](http://www.math.ku.dk/~rolf/HaganWest.pdf).

There is no easy formula, you will need a root-solver for the construction. I recommend the QuantLib library.